# PowerShell Replace Folder Name

Tags: powershell, tfsbuild

I am trying to copy some files from a build server to a staging server in a TFS build.  To do so, I am using a PowerShell script (single step) in a vNext build.  However, I cannot get the `-replace` to work.

When I run the following in the ISE client

```
[string] $thing0 = "K:\a\b\c"
[string] $thing1 = "$/Thing/Branch/Folder/Filename.ps1"
[string] $thing2 = $thing1 -replace "$/Thing/Branch/", $thing0

$thing2
```

`$thing2` should be `K:\a\b\c/Folder/Filename.ps1` but instead is unchanged.  How do I go about making this string replace work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-replace` parameter uses Regex search, where characters such as `$` have special meaning.

Instead, use the method:

```
[string] $thing2 = $thing1.Replace("$/Thing/Branch/",$thing0)
```

Comment: Ah, that does it.  Thanks much.  Will accept when SO lets me.